# Centos 7 - Apache failed to load after Yum update

Tags: centos, yum, update, failed

I got Centos 7 on my server. Yum update was not working because clamav was causing problem, so I deleted it. So it let me to do Yum Update. After that update was successful, but then apache server failed to load. How could I fix it? **Thank you!**

```
[root@waaaa ~]# systemctl -l status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-10-02 09:28:49 UTC; 12min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 2482 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2480 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2480 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com httpd[2480]: [Wed Oct 02 09:28:49.794195 2019] [so:warn] [pid 2480] AH01574: module unique_id_module is already loaded, skipping
Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com httpd[2480]: httpd: Syntax error on line 360 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/00_mod_security.conf: No matches for the wildcard '00*exclude.conf' in '/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d', failing (use IncludeOptional if required)
Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com kill[2482]: kill: cannot find process ""
Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Oct 02 09:28:49 waaaa.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Also I have check for "Apachectl configtest" and it gives out:

```
[root@waaaa ~]# apachectl configtest
[Wed Oct 02 09:46:16.221482 2019] [so:warn] [pid 6980] AH01574: module unique_id_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd: Syntax error on line 360 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/00_mod_security.conf: No matches for the wildcard '00*exclude.conf' in '/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d', failing (use IncludeOptional if required)
[root@waaaa ~]#
```

---

**Updated 12:51** 
File `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` in line 360 says `IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`

This is what included in `etc/httpd/conf.d/00_mod_security.conf`

`# ASL Free trial ruleset is available at: https://atomicorp.com/amember/signup/cart/`

`LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so`

`<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    # Basic configuration goes in here
    Include modsecurity.d/tortix_waf.conf`

```
# Rule management is handled by ASL
Include modsecurity.d/00*exclude.conf
Include modsecurity.d/*asl*.conf
Include modsecurity.d/99*exclude.conf
```

`</IfModule>`

Files in directory `/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d` :

`activated_rules`
`modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf`
`tortix_waf.conf`

Comment: Hi, Can you post or check the offending line? `line 13 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/00_mod_security.conf`. I think it is looking for "00*exclude.conf'". Was there a config file before? Maybe comment out that line and see if that let's you start? I think you need to carefully investigate and check to see what has changed after the yum update.

Comment: Thanks for replying. here is the code inside: 

`LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
 # Basic configuration goes in here
 Include modsecurity.d/tortix_waf.conf
 
 # Rule management is handled by ASL
 #Include modsecurity.d/00*exclude.conf
 Include modsecurity.d/*asl*.conf
 Include modsecurity.d/99*exclude.conf
</IfModule>`
I tried to comment out, then its says in line 14 of...
However, Mod_security in not installed in my server

Comment: Would you edit the question and add excerpt of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` line 360 and the whole `/etc/httpd/conf.d/00_mod_security.conf` and an `ls -la` of `/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d` ?

Comment: @Marco I have updated

Answer (score 1):

Since the included files do not exist, I think that if you edit `00_mod_security.conf` this way:

```
# Rule management is handled by ASL
IncludeOptional modsecurity.d/00*exclude.conf
IncludeOptional modsecurity.d/*asl*.conf
IncludeOptional modsecurity.d/99*exclude.conf
```

You'll get apache back running until you are able to reinstall and enable mod_security. Probably your upgrade disrupted the old mod_security, but we can't say since we don't know the way it has been originally installed.

Comment: Thanks @Marco, 
**I am get now a different error**

`[root@waaaa ~]# **apachectl configtest**`

`AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/domainx.co.uk/public_html] does not exist
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/www/domainx.co.uk/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/domainxco.uk.conf:1
AH00014: Configuration check failed`

Comment: It really seems you have the whole apache config messed up, like if you blindly updated from a very old version of Apache. I think you should review what you've done to find yourself in this situation in order to better understand, and then fix, and maybe then open a new question if you need more help, avoid turning this one in a troubleshooting/support chat.

Comment: Thanks Marco, 
I gave up, just restored to backup. :) Gonna give it a go next day

Comment: Read yum's warnings this time before Y :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no rogue config file calls that no longer exists.

Make sure EPEL Repository is enabled:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
```

Reinstall Mod_Sec:

```
yum install mod_security mod_security_crs
```

Make sure it's active:

Go to `etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf` at the `SecRuleEngine` zone.

Restart apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: In directory `/etc/httpd/conf.d` there is a file called  `00_mod_security.conf ` but not mod_security.conf 
Any thoughts?